# Chrome and Opera is not appending text to a div with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, opera

I have an issue with Chrome and Opera that I can't seem to find out how to fix. I have a popup blocker detector with javascript and if the blocker is enabled it will print out "Please enable popups for this site" in a div. This works great in FF, Safari and IE but not in Chrome and Opera. In those two browsers I do get the div collapsed with showing up but no text inside. Anyone have a work around for this and know what is going on? Thank you!

**JS**

```
function detectPopupBlocker() {
    var alertDiv = document.getElementById('popupAlert');
    console.log(alertDiv); // This prints to the console in Chrome and Opera
    var popupTest = window.open("about:blank","","directories=no,height=100,width=100,menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,titlebar=no,top=0,location=no");
    if (!popupTest) {
        alertDiv.innerHTML += 'Your popup blocker is detected.<br />Please enable popups for this site.';
    } else {
        popupTest.close();
    }
}
window.onload = detectPopupBlocker;
```

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors in chrome dev tools? Perhaps it is tripping up when alertDiv.innerHtml is undefined.

Comment: No, I'm not getting any errors in dev tools

Comment: Wait, what??? Why are you setting `alertDiv.innerHTML` equal to itself? why not just do `alertDiv.innerHTML = 'your text here'` ???

Comment: If you put `console.log(popupTest)` just before `if`, you can see, that in Chrome and Opera it'll be `[window Object]` despite of blocked pop-up.

Comment: @Teemu I added that and got this: `Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}`

Comment: @ryan if I don't have `alertDiv.innerHTML` equal itself it doesn't work at all

Comment: @urbanrunic Obviously it's not `null/false/undefined` like in other browsers, and testing the existense fails...

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that, if you want to keep what was in the popup, do `alertDiv.innerHTML += 'your text here'`

Comment: Did that fix the problem you were having?

Comment: @ryan nope, it's still not printing to the div in Opera and Chrome

Comment: @urbanrunic Opera and Chrome return an object, even the pop-up was blocked, hence execution will jump straight to the `else` in those browsers. Just copy the `alertDiv.innerHTML += 'Your...` to the `else` block, and you'll see...

Comment: @Teemu, if you would like...put this as an answer and I'll mark it for  you. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opera and Chrome return an object from `window.open()`, even if the pop-up was blocked, hence execution will jump straight to the `else` in these browsers. This means, that you can't detect, if pop-up blocker is on in Chrome or Opera, with your current code.

However, you can try to detect, if there's a known element available in the `popupTest`, though in this case you need to load a real file to the pop-up instead of `about:blank`.

```
var isPopup = false,
    popupTest = window.open(...);
try {
    if (popupTest.document.getElementById('a_known_id')) {
        isPopup = true;
    }
} catch (err) {isPopup = false;}
if (isPopup) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are (or were) two good reasons for making window.open() return a fake window object when popup blocker is enabled:

1. Some site / apps might try to detect popup blocking and force the user to disable the blocker and endure ads and other abuse
2. Back when we implemented popup blocking, we often saw scripts that would break if there was no return object. I.e. if they wanted to check win.closed but 'win' was set to undefined.

This "feature" may no longer be required since some browsers implement popup blocking differently.